# How can this pushViewController statement work in the tutorial I am doing?

Tags: iphone, ios, pushviewcontroller

I am doing a tutorial from the book "Beginning iPhone 4 Development" and in Chapter 09 they have the following snippet of code:

http://www.apress.com/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/5/

```
#import "FirstLevelViewController.h"
#import "SecondLevelViewController.h"
#import "DisclosureButtonController.h"

@implementation FirstLevelViewController


@synthesize controllers;



-(void)viewDidLoad{

    self.title=@"First Level";  
    NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //Disclosure Button 
    DisclosureButtonController *disclosureButtonController = [[DisclosureButtonController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

    disclosureButtonController.title = @"Disclosure Buttons";
    disclosureButtonController.rowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"disclosureButtonControllerIcon.png"];
    [array addObject:disclosureButtonController];
    [disclosureButtonController release];

    self.controllers = array;
    [array release];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}


-(void)viewDidUnload{

    self.controllers = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}


-(void)dealloc{
    [controllers release];
    [super dealloc];
}



#pragma mark -

#pragma mark Table Data Source Methods
-(NSInteger) tableView: (UITableView *)tableView
numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [self.controllers count];

}


-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath{


    static NSString *FirstLevelCell = @"FirstLevelCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:FirstLevelCell];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:FirstLevelCell]autorelease];
    }


    //configure the cell
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    DisclosureButtonController *controller = [controllers objectAtIndex:row];
    cell.textLabel.text=controller.title;
    cell.imageView.image = controller.rowImage;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;


}

#pragma mark - 
#pragma mark Table View Delegate Methods

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    SecondLevelViewController *nextController = [controllers objectAtIndex:row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];


}



@end
```

The very last statement:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
```

makes no sense to me because essentially you are pushing the same existing controller. However when I compile the app and run, everything works just fine. My question is how is this app allowing me to go to the next screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The very last statement makes no sense to me because essentially you are pushing the same existing controller.

You're not pushing the same existing controller, you're pushing the **nextController**, which comes from the *controllers* array:

> **nextController** = [*controllers* objectAtIndex:row];
>
> [self.navigationController pushViewController:**nextController** animated:YES];

Comment: I see that but the controllers array does not seem to have information about the next view which gets pushed. I know you are right but if you download the project from the link it will give you whole picture. I'm going to look at code again. Sorry for being a newb.

Comment: The controllers array is populated in -viewDidLoad, and contains a list of all the view controllers that can get pushed on to the UINavigationController stack.